# JQuery Mobile 1.4 selectmenu within popup

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova-3

I have the following code:

```
var rkIssueDatabaseManager = new RkIssueDatabaseManager();
rkIssueDatabaseManager.listRiskLevels().done(function (riskLevels) {
    var optionsHtml = "";

    $.each(riskLevels, function () {
        if (this.default_val) {
            optionsHtml += "<option value='" + this.id + "' selected=''>" + this.description + "</option>";
        } else {
            optionsHtml += "<option value='" + this.id + "'>" + this.description + "</option>";
        }
    });

    $("<select>").attr({id: "rk-issue-risk", name: "risk_level_id", "data-native-menu": "false"}).html(optionsHtml).appendTo("#rk-issues-content");
    $("#rk-issue-risk").selectmenu();
});
```

This code is executed in the pagebeforeshow event and appends the selectmenu into a hidden popup that will be shown only when the user clicks a button.

When the popup is shown, the selectmenu is initialized properly whith the right selected value, but when pressed, its menu is show in the native L&F even if I have set the "data-native-menu" to false and also in my application init I've set the global property to false.

```
$.mobile.selectmenu.prototype.options.nativeMenu = false;
```

I tested this same code, but appended the selectmenu directly to an element in the page instead of the popup and the L&F was the right one.

Any known issue with none-native L&F on selectmenu inside a popup?

**EDIT**

I was able to create a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/euphreme/mkfte260/)

Comment: Because non-native (custom) selectmenus can only be used inside a page. Although dialog is a page-like, you can't use dialog/popup inside a dialog. Custom selectmenus are converted into popup or dialog depending on length of option as well as viewport's height. Edit: you're using a popup not a dialog, anyway, the aforementioned applies to popups too.

Comment: So, In order to get a constant L&F, I would need to create my own html select?